# Как нарисовать дерево по заданной строке (в ней описаны узлы)?

Tags: java, рекурсия, дерево

В скобках находится узел дерева, первый элемент - вершина, остальные - потомки. Нужно вывести дерево по исходной строке (примеры на картинках).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом нужно создать класс TreeNode.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста весь текст из картинок вставьте именно текстом в ваш вопрос. Что вы уже пытались сделать, что именно не получилось? И почему во втором примере 7 является ребенком abc, а не x? Какие критерии форматирования? Почему везде между вершинами по одному пробелу, а между x и y два?

Comment: Картинки не соответствовали условию. Исправил их. Код для визуального представления программы у меня уже есть. Например, есть программа для вычисления чисел Фибоначчи через рекурсию. Рекурсия вызывает саму себя, пока не вернет единицу, а затем все оставшиеся значения. Мне здесь нужно также спускаться по узлам, чтобы вернуть 7, потом х, потом uuu, потом опять спуститься и вернуть 1, затем 10 и т.д. Вот как именно разобрать исходную строку и написать этот спуск, чтобы он возвращал нужные вершины в нужном порядке, я понять не могу.

Comment: Не очень понятен язык описания. Первый элемент в скобке является родителем последующих? Это работает для abc, но не для uuu